# How to create top tabs in React Navigation v3?

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation

I can see for the documentation that v3's createTabNavigator has been removed. It was replaced with `createBottomTabNavigator`, `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` and `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator`.

I am using createBottomTabNavigator for the main screen navigation but **would like to have Tabs at the top of each screen** for categories of content.

We are not using material design in this project so the `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` option done not help use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`createMaterialTopTabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html) and customize its styling options via `tabBarOptions` to fit the design of your project.

If you need more customization than is given, then you can override the `tabBarComponent` with your own. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/react-navigation/tabs/blob/master/src/views/MaterialTopTabBar.js) for the `tabBarComponent` that `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` uses by default as reference for creating your own custom `tabBarComponent`.

For clarity in why `createTabNavigator` was removed in 3.0, here's the [React Navigation 2.0 release notes](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/05/07/react-navigation-2.0.html). What `createTabNavigator` used to do was use `createBottomTabNavigator` on iOS and `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` on Android, which was not practical if you wanted your app to look the same on both devices, so it was split into those two functions.